# Reactjs: Using vaueLink with radiobuttons

Tags: reactjs

Is there a way to use valueLink with radio buttons? It's not mentioned in [the two-way-binding documentation](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/two-way-binding-helpers.html) and I can't seem to figure it out otherwise. Or do I need to handle radio buttons manually with checked values and onChange handlers?

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own mixin. Something like this:

```
var LinkedStateRadioGroupMixin = {
    radioGroup : function(key){
        return {
            valueLink : function(value){
                return {
                    value : this.state[key] == value,
                    requestChange : function(){
                        var s = {};
                        s[key] = value;
                        this.setState(s) 
                    }.bind(this)  
                }
            }.bind(this)
        }
    }
}

var RegisterForm = React.createClass({
    mixins : [
        LinkedStateRadioGroupMixin
    ],
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            accountType : 'developer'
        };
    },
    register : function(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        alert(this.state.accountType)
    },
    render : function(){
        var accountType = this.radioGroup("accountType");
        return <form onSubmit={this.register}>
            <label>Manager:
                <input checkedLink={accountType.valueLink("manager")} type="radio" />
            </label>
            <label>Developer:
                <input checkedLink={accountType.valueLink("developer")} type="radio"/>
            </label>
            <button>register</button>
        </form>
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

`ReactLink` is [very tiny](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/src/addons/link/ReactLink.js) (about a dozen lines).  It only handles elements that have "normal" value attributes.  Radio button value attributes act differently, React uses the `checked` attribute [for radio buttons](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html).  You can still use `ReactLink` [for bookkeeping](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/two-way-binding-helpers.html#reactlink-without-valuelink) if you like, see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3pbrr2x9/) for an example.  It wouldn't be too much work to write a mixin to handle the radio button case; use the `ReactLink` [source](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/src/addons/link/ReactLink.js) as a starting point.

docs:

- [ReactLink source](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/src/addons/link/ReactLink.js)
- [forms docs](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html)
- [ReactLink without valueLink](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/two-way-binding-helpers.html#reactlink-without-valuelink)

**EDIT:** There does seem to be a `checkedLink` handler in the `LinkedValueUtils`, but I can't really figure out how that's supposed to work.  See [the code here](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/0a5c22264b2e628e533657c576c90a18282813b8/src/browser/ui/dom/components/LinkedValueUtils.js#L135).

**EDIT 2:** The `checkedLink` handler is [only for checkboxes](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/16dfaca66a3f656a5a7d7b320c147f7c532bab15/docs/_posts/2014-02-20-react-v0.9.md#react-with-addons).  Perhaps a future release will see radio button support, which is more likely if one of us submits a PR.